# Borland compiler can't handle inheriting from a class with a template template argument?

Tags: c++, borland-c++

```
template <class, template<class> class R>
struct T1
{};

template<class>
struct O
{};

template <class A>
class T2:
    public T1<A,O>
{
public:
    T2() : T1<A,O>()
    {}
};

T2<int> p;
```

With the code above it gives the following error: `E2312 'T1<int,O<{param1}> >' is not an unambiguous base class of 'T2<int>'`

But if I were to remove the first template parameter of `T1`

```
template <template<class> class R>
struct T1
{};

template<class>
struct O
{};

template <class A>
class T2:
    public T1<O>
{
public:
    T2() : T1<O>()
    {}
};

T2<int> p;
```

or in `T2` inherit not with the template parameter by with a hard-coded type

```
template <class, template<class> class R>
struct T1
{};

template<class>
struct O
{};

template <class A>
class T2:
    public T1<int,O>
{
public:
    T2() : T1<int,O>()
    {}
};

T2<int> p;
```

then it compiles.

Do you have any ideas what could be the problem? This problem occurs only with Borland compiler...

I understand, I should rather ask the supplier, but maybe someone has already dealt with the problem.

Compiler version:

```
>bcc32.exe --version
Embarcadero C++ 7.40 for Win32 Copyright (c) 1993-2018 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
Preliminary version built Aug 23 2019 08:48:10
Revision 7.40.7174.37042
```

Comment: What is the version of the compiler?

Comment: @SeanFrancisN.Ballais, updated

Comment: [`bcc32.exe`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/BCC32.EXE,_the_C%2B%2B_32-bit_Command-Line_Compiler) is the old pre-C++11 32bit compiler created by Borland before Embarcadero bought it. `bcc32.exe` is provided only for backwards compatibility with legacy code, so don't expect it to support things in modern C++ versions. Use one of the newer Clang-based 32bit compilers for that, [`bcc32c.exe`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/BCC32C.EXE) and [`bcc32x.exe`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/BCC32X.EXE), which both support up to C++17.

Comment: `bcc32.exe` wasn't very good at supporting more complex template usages, which could explain why this isn't working until the offending template is simplified.